# Why does my Bing Translate code work perfect in all browsers except Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, api, bing

I've a simple Bing Translate example, but it does not work with google chrome.

I don't understand whether it is a bing problem or my code is wrong.

This is the code of my example

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">  
   function translate() {
   document.getElementById('trans').innerHTML="";
   var text= document.getElementById('ori').value;
   window.mycallback = function(response) {
   document.getElementById('trans').innerHTML=response;
   }

   var languageFrom = document.getElementById("langpairFROM").value;
   var languageTo = document.getElementById("langpairTO").value;
   var s = document.createElement("script");
   s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?oncomplete=mycallback&appId=68D088969D79A8B23AF8585CC83EBA2A05A97651&from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&text=" + text;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
   }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>


<select id="langpairFROM" STYLE=" font-size : 11pt">
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>                                         
</select>

<select id="langpairTO" STYLE=" font-size : 11pt">
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>  
</select>

<button type="input" onclick="translate()" >Translate</button> 

<div >
  <textarea id="ori" name="translate" ></textarea> 
</div>

<div id="translationField">
  <textarea id="trans" >Translated Text</textarea> 
</div
</center>
</body> 

</html>
```

[Here ist the jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/n9YLp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you also has a `<textarea>` named `translate`.

Change either the function name or the `<textarea>` name:

[JSFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/n9YLp/1/)

PS. I assumed you use something like `encodeURIComponent` to "sanitize" your url in production code.

Answer (score 0):

I have mended your code. It now works for Chrome as well

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function translate() {
  document.getElementById('translate_to').innerHTML="";
  var text= document.getElementById('translate_from').value;
  window.mycallback = function(response) {
  document.getElementById('translate_to').innerHTML=response;
}

var languageFrom = document.getElementById("langpairFROM").value;
var languageTo = document.getElementById("langpairTO").value;
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?oncomplete=mycallback&appId=68D088969D79A8B23AF8585CC83EBA2A05A97651&from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&text=" + text;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="javascript:translate()">
<center>
<select id="langpairFROM" STYLE=" font-size : 11pt">
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="en" selected>English</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>                                         
</select>
<select id="langpairTO" STYLE=" font-size : 11pt">
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
  <option value="de" selected>German</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>  
</select>
<button type="submit">Translate</button> 
<div >
  <textarea id="translate_from" name="translate_from" ></textarea> 
</div>
<div id="translationField">
  <textarea id="translate_to" >Translated Text</textarea> 
</div
</center>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```